# Command and Control Infrastructure

Tags: botnet

This is an academic question, I googled a lot but couldn't find suitable answers for this question:

> What are the different Command & Control infrastructures (Botnets) &
>   what are the countermeasures?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_and_control_(malware)#Architecture_of_Command_and_Control_types)?
In short, the malware (A) needs to connect to (B).
This can be done using many different methods.

The easiest (in my opinion) to setup is by using the **HTTP (Webserver)** protocol.
You make a simple web server with short PHP scripts that handle the incoming requests. You send/ask for requests by using sockets (for example) the Windows API.

**Countermeasure:** Blocking this specific domain/IP Address in your firewall. I should mention that malware often has multiple server addresses hard-coded into its source to countermeasure this countermeasure. 
If you're working at a security company/government the countermeasure would be contacting the host-provider to take down that website, or in some cases even hack the server.

Another much used is by using **IRC** chatrooms. You create a secured and private IRC chatroom, and than you can 'chat' with your malware. In other words, you send a command into the chat-box, and the malware ('reading' the chat messages) will receive the commands and execute them. IRC is mainly used because of simplicity and its low bandwidth requirements.

**Countermeasure:** Block specific TCP ports like 6667 (specific to IRC), again I should mention that IRC tries other ports as well if 6667 is blocked.

What also is often used is **P2P** (Peer-to-peer), you use your own connection/computers as a C&C server. The malware communicates directly with your network to receive commands.
This is what you most of the time use with frameworks like Metasploit.

**Countermeasure:** Here the IP of the attacker would be static, so simply blocking that IP should work. Again, if you're working in a security company/government, you can log the IP and with luck you have the IP of the attacker. The attacker could also use a VPN allowing port-forwarding, but then it isn't real P2P anymore.

As you see, your firewall is important.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add **DNS** to O'Niels answer:

Some botnets use DNS tunneling to communicate between botmaster and bots. F.e. you can (ab)use [TXT records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TXT_record) to transmit data. As this is an academic question [here's a good paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6377756/) on this topic (requires IEEE access or maybe you can find it on Google as well).

**Countermeasure:** This one is tricky. Quoting the above paper:

> Even in environments with heavily restricted Internet access, e.g. by
>   means of firewalling and proxying, DNS is usually one of the few
>   protocols – if not the only one – that is allowed to pass without
>   further ado.

Of course you can't simply block all your DNS traffic. Instead monitoring your DNS traffic and looking for anomalies might be a solution. Above paper suggests a anomaly detection based on entropy. Simpler approaches (mentioned [here](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/dns-tunnelling/)) could be to use a IDS or searching for large DNS requests and DNS TXT records.